# How to subset a data frame using variable from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, iteration, subset

I have the below question about how to subset a dataframe with a for loop using another data frame to insert values into the for loop.

```
bf=read.csv('Branched_Fields.csv')

bf

  ID    field1 field1a field1b field2 field2a error loc
1 1000     NA       1       1      1       2          
2 1001      1       2       2      2      NA          
3 1003     NA       1       3      2       2          
4 1202      1      NA      NA      2      NA          
5 1345      2      NA      NA     NA       2          
6 1234      2       2       3      2      NA          
7 1234     NA      NA       3     NA       2          
8 4564     NA       2      NA      2       2 

bf$error <- ""
bf$loc <- ""
```

bf is a data frame with 8 IDs, which have completed a survey with questions branch off of the previous questions. I want to create a subset dataframe with the list of IDs that have not answered each survey question, but I only want the NA instance included in the list if the survey respondent was supposed to see the question.

The below code works well to write to the data frame "combined" with the ID of each instance of an NA, and where the NA is located (what field).

```
field1 <- subset(bf, is.na(field1), select=c(ID, error))
field1$error="field1 = NA"
combined <- field1

field1a <- subset(bf, field1>0 & is.na(field1a), select=c(ID, error))
field1a$error="field1a = NA"
combined <- field1a

field1b <- subset(bf, field1>0 & is.na(field1b), select=c(ID, error))
field1b$error="field1a = NA"
combined <- field1b

field2 <- subset(bf, is.na(field2), select=c(ID, error))
field2$error="field1a = NA"
combined <- field2

field2a <- subset(bf, field2>0 & is.na(field2a), select=c(ID, error))
field2a$error="field1a = NA"
combined <- field2a
```

This results in the below data frame, which is exactly what I need. But I need to do this with a survey with over 1,000 questions. Can I make a for loop or a function to through this?

```
     ID        error
1  1000  field1 = NA
3  1003  field1 = NA
7  1234  field1 = NA
8  4564  field1 = NA
4  1202 field1a = NA
5  1345 field1a = NA
41 1202 field1a = NA
51 1345 field1a = NA
52 1345 field1a = NA
71 1234 field1a = NA
2  1001 field1a = NA
42 1202 field1a = NA
6  1234 field1a = NA
```

I think the first step in looping through this is to make a table of all of the variables that change each iteration, like below.

This is data frame fl

```
Field_Name   Branched         Label
1     field1            field1 = NA
2    field1a field1>0 field1a  = NA
3    field1b field1>0 field1b  = NA
4     field2           field2  = NA
5    field2a field2>0 field2a  = NA
```

I am very new to R and do not know much about for loops and I know this is wrong, but this is what I was thinking.

```
for row in fl, 
     fl$Field_Name <- subset(bf, is.na(fl$Field_Name), select=c(ID, error))
     fl$Field_Name=fl$Label
     combined <- field2
```

In this case, I don't know how to handle the case where some questions are branched off of others and some questions are not.

This is my first question, so please be kind if this was asked incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert your data into a "tidy" format See [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) for more details. But for your specific problem try something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

n <- 10
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(id=1:n
             ,field1=sample(c(1:5,NA),n,replace = T)
             ,field2=sample(c(1:5,NA),n,replace = T)
             ,field3=sample(c(1:5,NA),n,replace = T)
             ,field4=sample(c(1:5,NA),n,replace = T)
             )
df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>       id field1 field2 field3 field4
#>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#>  1     1      3     NA      1      1
#>  2     2     NA      1      5      3
#>  3     3      3      2      3      5
#>  4     4      2      3      2      4
#>  5     5      2      5      2      2
#>  6     6     NA      3      1      5
#>  7     7      3      3     NA      1
#>  8     8      5      1      3      1
#>  9     9      4      4      4      2
#> 10    10     NA      1     NA      3
df %>% 
  gather('field','value',-id) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  filter(is.na(value))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id field  value
#>   <int> <chr>  <int>
#> 1     1 field2    NA
#> 2     2 field1    NA
#> 3     6 field1    NA
#> 4     7 field3    NA
#> 5    10 field1    NA
#> 6    10 field3    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm still looking into it, but learning about creating data in the tidy format will be really helpful for a lot of the projects that I am working on now. Unfortunately, this does't account for when fields are supposed to be blank, which I still have to figure out.  Thanks again!